# No error while web debugger running on the background but throws HttpRequestException when the web dubugger is off

Tags: c#, exception, fiddler

I am using a web server to get the data. Whenever I access the web server the data gets uploaded in the CSV file n later it goes to database.

I am using Fiddler4 to check the connection with web server. When the fiddler is running at the background the code works good. But when the fiddler is off it gives HTTPRequestException.

This is the code that I am using:

```
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url of web server))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
      //write a csv file 
    }
```

Anything I am missing ?

Comment: To use Fiddler you usually have to configure the caller to use Fiddler as a Proxy.  Are you sure you removed this configuration from your caller?